# Recieve data in inner attr using XPath

Tags: python, html, parsing, xpath

I want to get text inside `div` and inner attributes like `ul` and `li`

My hierarchy of html is looks like below

```
<div>
  text
  <ul>
     <li>text</li>
     <li>text</li>
     <li>text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So I could get div text using `xpath('div/text()')` function, but I am stuck in getting other text inside inner attributes. Can someone help me how to do it correctly.

Comment: Can we use BeautifulSoup?

Comment: I want to do it using xpath, but if I will not find the way to solve the problem I am going to use BeautifulSoup

Comment: Okay, I posted an answer using both the approaches. see if it helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

test = '''<div>text_0<ul>
     <li>text_1</li>
     <li>text_2</li>
     <li>text_3</li>
  </ul>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(test, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all("div")
for d in data:
    print(d.text)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
text_0
text_1
text_2
text_3
```

Using `xpath`:

```
import lxml.html as LH

content = '''<div>text_0<ul>
     <li>text_1</li>
     <li>text_2</li>
     <li>text_3</li>
  </ul>
</div>'''
root = LH.fromstring(content)
for elem in root.xpath('//div/descendant::text()'):
    print(elem)
```